# Is an inﬁnite union of context-free languages always context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Let $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$, $\dots$ be an inﬁnite sequence of context-free languages, each of
which is deﬁned over a common alphabet $Σ$. Let $L$ be the inﬁnite union of $L_1$, $L_2$, $L_3$, $\dots $;
i.e., $L = L_1 \cup L_2 \cup L_3 \cup \dots $.

Is it always the case that $L$ is a context-free language?

Comment: There are two mostly independent questions here. The first is very elementary, but the second is even easily answered with Wikipedia. I suggest you edit to focus on the first question.

Comment: @Raphael: I did it myself before your suggestion but then I thought it might make some parts of the answers useless.

Comment: @Raphael: That edit nullifies most of what I wrote! I don't think it is a good idea to be morphing questions like that, when there are answers already.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Is it possible to edit your answer please? I edited it to prevent the question from being easy as he said! I'll post a meta question about this.

Comment: @Gigili: I can, but I was talking in general terms. Imagine the case where someone does some 
research, and puts in some effort to write a detailed answer. Now you go and change the question which invalidates most of that answer. For this question it might not matter, in fact, I can probably just delete my answer, as we will have two answers saying the same thing and one of them would just be noise.

Comment: [Ensuing meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89/please-edit-your-question-its-easy)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93464/755

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The union of infinitely many context-free languages may not be context free. In fact, the union of infinitely many languages can be just about anything: let $L$ be a language, and define for every $l \in L$ the (finite) language $L_l = \{ l \}$. The union over all these languages is $L$. Finite languages are regular, but $L$ may not even be decidable (and thereby definitely not context-free).

The closure properties of context-free languages can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure_properties).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the answer is "no"? Could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: @Gigili: the language $\{ a^n b^n c^n | n \geq 1 \}$ is the usual example of a language that is not context-free, and using my construction the union of $L_1 = \{ a b c \}, L_2 = \{ aa bb cc \}, L_3 = \{ aaa bbb ccc \}, \dots$ is exactly that language, but all the $L_i$ are finite and therefore context-free.

Comment: @Gigili You should be able to use any not context-free language as counter example using what Alex has written.

Comment: Another way to break down any language is according to the lengths of the words: $L = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{w \in L \mid |w| \le n\}$. This shows that even an increasing union of finite languages is enough to describe any language.

Comment: "In fact, the union of infinitely many languages can be **just about anything**" (emphasis added)  Actually, it can be anything, period, no "just about".  Your example shows that. Well, the null set/language may be an issue, but empty unions are fine. So, it can be the weirdest, vastly non-computable set, as far up any hierarchy as you'd like to go. It can be **any** set.