# Infinite Union of Recursive language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

### Question

> Is **Infinite Union** of Recursive language is **Recursive**?

I know it is already posted [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/206/is-an-in%EF%AC%81nite-union-of-context-free-languages-always-context-free), but the i am not getting answer also i want to know if my approach is correct.

#### My Approach/Doubt

$\text{let}\,\,L_1=abcd \,\,\,L_2=a^2b^2c^2d^2=aabbccdd,L_3=a^3b^3c^3d^3=aaabbbcccddd$

here $L_{1},L_{2},L_{3}\,....\text{are finite hence regular hence recursive}$

let $L_{Iu}=L_1 \,\cup\,L_2\,\cup\,L_3\,\cup........$

but $L_{Iu}=a^{n}b^{n}c^{n} \text{which is recursive }$ .

so can i say that **Infinite Union** of Recursive language is **Recursive**

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every finite language is recursive.

Every language can be written as an infinite union of finite languages.

Some language isn't recursive.

Comment: sir, that means  $\text{none of regular,cfl,csl,recursive and recursive enumerable are closed under Infinite union}$

Comment: Right. If a family of languages contains all singletons (i.e., $\{w\}$) and is closed under arbitrary union, then it either contains all languages or all languages except the empty one.